# Websocket connection failed React JS

Tags: reactjs

I just created a new React App and every time i navigate to a new path i get these errors:
[image of the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0Agq.png)
I don't know if it's a problem in the packages or what cause i just created this app and this are all the routes that i have in app.js:

```
import Home from './views/Home';
import {BrowserRouter, Route, Routes} from 'react-router-dom'
import Test from './views/Test';
import React from 'react';
import Register from './views/Register';
function App() {
return (
<div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path='/register' element={<Register />} />
    <Route path='/' element={<Home/>} />
    <Route path='/test' element={<Test />} />
  </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
 

</div>
 );
}

export default App;
```

The application is working normally but i think that error is slowing down the performance of the app

Comment: port 59548 is the port you use for your react app ?

Comment: No @Johan the app lunchs on "http://localhost:3000/" i didn't change anything.

Comment: Then err shows you have a connection to port 59548. We can't help you more with these informations. Please provide the commands you used and the context

Comment: @johan , the context of what? i just generated the app with the command npx create-react-app and the npm start i did nothing with the ports